# Command to clear shell terminal?

Tags: python, shell

I'm Currently using python 3.5.2 shell for practicing. I'm beginner for the python and while practicing I tried clearing the shell terminal with CTRL+L command but its not clearing the shell. Appreciate any other commands for clearing the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can install ipython if you want to still use CTRL+L

```
pip install ipython
```